# What's the smallest float allowable for exponentialRampToValueAtTime?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

`exponentialRampToValueAtTime(value, time)` triggers an error if `value` is 0, which makes sense since log of 0 is undefined, but apparently also triggers an error if `value` is too close to 0 like `1e-150`.

What's the smallest number value possible for the value parameter?

Comment: Looking at [the spec](http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#widl-AudioParam-value) and the [WebKit source](https://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/Modules/webaudio/AudioParam.h?rev=179838) I'm assuming values have to be [32bit single precision floats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: While I agree that well-defined limits are desirable, are you sure using the smallest possible value is useful? Wouldn't that produce a fast ramp down to inaudibility well before the specified time?

Comment: Interesting ... why would an exponential ramp do that if the approaching value is too small?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the minimum normal value of a 32 bit float, which would be 2 to the -126, or about 1.18e-38. The spec doesn't actually say it has to be a normal value, but I wouldn't mess around with denormal values; it can reduce performance (or just round to zero on some hardware).

Of course 1.18-38 is a ridiculously small gain value, and such small numbers will just be rounded to zero anyway when the samples are converted to integers and sent to the sound hardware. You might as well use a larger value, like 1/32768, unless you're passing it through some later high-gain stages for some reason.

BUT

When you're ramping to silence, you probably shouldn't be using exponentialRampToValueAtTime anyway. You should use setTargetAtTime. This lets you control how fast the exponential ramp is. It also means you don't have to worry about minimum allowed target values, because you can use zero as the target.